# How to change Microsoft SharePoint Data Encryption (Obfuscation) setting for GraphAPI reports?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

By default when a new SharePoint site is created and reports are requested in graph API the result is returned with corrupted/modified data. This requires updating organization settings for the data conceal. Where can I find this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to Admin Center. Navigate to Settings >> Org Settings >> Services >> Reports, uncheck “Display concealed user, group, and site names in all reports” checkbox and save to solve the issue.